# Current user always null immediately after sign in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm having a problem where after I successfully sign a user in to my application I want to get that user. My problem is that the user is always `null`. The odd thing is that I use the exact same method elsewhere to successfully get the current user.

As someone new to .NET I'm not sure why it's not working for me.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    EmailModel emailModel = new EmailModel {
        toEmail = model.Email,
        subject = " ",
        message = " "
    };

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

    // user here is always null
    await _emailService.SendTestEmail(emailModel, user);

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: That's normal because the `User` property will only be set on the **next** request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to find the User from the HttpContext, but when the HttpContext was set for the controller the User is null as it did not yet exist at the time the controller was instantiated.

Use

```
var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email)
```

instead in this case